# How to test application without activating it?

Tags: android, google-play, android-lvl

OK, so I exported a signed release APK, "locked" with Google's LVL API but before activating it on Google Play to be visible to and downloadable by all, I want to test it first on my device.

The problem is when I just `adb install -r` that signed release APK, the licensing server returns `NOT_LICENSED` and **I cannot test the locked features**.

What is the proper way to test an application locked with Google's LVL without activating it first?

Comment: Upload your app on Google Play, do not activate it.

Comment: @yorkw I did. But the licensing server keeps returning `NOT_LICENSED`. I ended up gambling by activating it and waiting the ~1 hour or so for it to become available. If it turns out to be buggy I will re-activate the older version. But that's so unprofessional... There's got to be a better way. +1 for now.

Comment: On your device, try clear app data under `Settings -> Applications -> Manage application -> Google Play`.

Comment: @yorkw It worked! Please post this trick of clearing app data under `Settings -> Applications -> Manage application -> Google Play` as an answer so that I can accept it. Thanks +1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remember I had similiar problem before, when google rename Android Market to Google Play. It seems that Google Play is stuck with the old LVL cached data.

Try clearing app data under `Settings -> Applications -> Manage Applications -> Google Play` on your device.