# LVL Library Google Play licensing response code always NOT LICENSED for test accounts

Tags: android, google-play, android-lvl

I've added licensing to my android application using LVL Library. Licensing works properly for normal users which buys it in Google Play (I think so - I don't have any feedback about problems). It worked also when I primarily tested it on second device with some test account.

Currently I have problem that server always return NOT_LICENSED response code (1) on devices with test account whatever I set in "license test answer" in developer console. When I test on  device with publisher account answer is correct (server returns what I set in "license test answer").

I've tested on signed release build and on debug build and always the same. I've the same release build uploaded to Google Play (and use the same versionCode for debug version as this which was uploaded).
I've tested with single (primary??) test account configured on test device.

Interesting thing - to device with primary test account I've added publisher account (settings/accounts and synch/add account), and answer is still always NOT_LICENSED even if there is publisher account on it. Unfortunatelly I cannot delete test account from that device because I have some data which I don't want to delete.

I gave apk to other testers and added test accounts for them - they have the same issue - always NOT_LICENSED response.

Comment: See if the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023152/how-to-test-application-without-activating-it/11024829#11024829) helps.

Comment: I forgotten to write that I have tried this also with no success.

Answer (score 4):

i had the same issue for an app that was already published:
If you count up your `android:versionCode` in the Manifest, higher than the currently published version, the play store will always return not_licensed.
So the solution is to NOT count up the version code while you are testing.
The behaviour is strange but this solution worked for me.

Comment: Worked for me. I guess if you want to increment `versionCode`, then you should upload the apk to Google Play (as alpha/beta) so that it is aware that such version exists.