# Play Store LicenseCheck with wrong results

Tags: android, google-play, android-lvl

I've made a new app for Google play store and try to use LVL in it. The app is already uploaded to my developer console but not yet published.
I added my gmail account to the test accounts and it seems to work, I get the correct answers from the google server (LICENSED or NOT_LICENSED).
But when I try this with a different google account that is NOT in my test account list, I always get the LICENSED message. I expect the answer NOT_LICENSED.

Has anyone experienced something similar or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [license reference](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/google/play/licensing/licensing-reference.html#server-response-codes):

> LICENSED  The application is licensed to the user. The user has purchased the application **or the application only exists as a draft**.

Comment: So everything is fine. Thank you!

Comment: @Korcholis I am doing this license application for may app i am getting only Not Licensed for tested accounts and other accounts also. I posted my apk and saved as like draft and then tested there is no change in the results please help.me..

Comment: You should look for an answer in SO and, if it didn't exist, post a new question. This solution stands for a different situation, so it is not related. However, in a pretty fast search, I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11122371/lvl-library-google-play-licensing-response-code-always-not-licensed-for-test-acc/12581325#12581325)

Comment: Thanq for respnse..i already searched a lot.. and related to those answers i checked my app.. but still i facing the same problem.. thatswhy followed u..